# HDMI switching Board

Tags: hardware, display

Quite simply  I would like to have a board, if one exists, that i can plug my TV stream (the cord that comes from my cable box) into the Pi and have an HDMI come out of the pi to the TV. Using python the Pi itself could switch between the TV and the Pi.

Comment: A remote controlled HDMI switch is probably easier. You plug the Pi and your cable box into it and connect the switch to the TV. I use this one http://www.amazon.com/IOGEAR-3-Port-Switch-Remote-GHDSW3/dp/B004JN55JU/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1435875280&sr=8-1&keywords=hdmi+switch+iogear.

Comment: I'd prefer it be directly controllable via the Pi. Is that possible?

Comment: Use the GPIO pins to operate an IR LED or modify the remote to be switched via the GPIO pins.

Comment: I'm not sure I could do that with my current knowledge...

Answer (score 1):

You have 3 options to connect to tv and send command to it

- rs232 serial port
- Lan
- Hdmi cec

You need to check your tv and found out which one is supported .

Answer (score 0):

Ern, sorry if I'm being too harsh. Just exactly when did HDMI-CEC commands went vintage? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Consumer_Electronics_Control

You can send a "switch input to HDMI" signal to most modern TVs. In fact, some Raspberry Pi mediacenter distros like XBian does it out of the box. Worth a try, looks exactly like what you need.

Answer (score -1):

This could be the thing you are searching for in this video:
https://vimeo.com/153959180

And this is a link to the product page:
http://www.auvidea.eu/index.php/theme-styles/2014-12-30-22-32-06/b101

Comment: MHMr, welcome to the site. If you haven't already, please take a look at the [tour](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/tour). Link only answers are discouraged as they're subject to link rot. While we don't discourage the use of links, they should be accompanied by a description that covers the basics of what they are and what the solution may be.